# SQL, quering data from one table with criteria from another

Tags: sql

I don't have much experience with SQL and I'm pretty much lost when it comes to anything more advanced than simple INSERT/SELECT statements.

My scenario is this, I have the following two tables:

Games
{
int id, int finished
}

Submissions
{
int game_id,int user_id
}

And I want to query any id from Games where finished=0 and a specific user_id is not tied together with the id in mind in the Submissions table.

So in other words, I want to find a game that isn't finished and a specific user haven't played.

I know I can do this with multiple queries and logic (in java and jdbc if it matters), but I rather learn how to do it with pure SQL!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a table where you store all the users?

Comment: Yes. But I don't think that's relevant to the question, no?

Comment: It's relevant as far as efficiency is concerned (the best approach varies. [For SQL Server Not Exists wins](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/)) also In Oracle you would use `minus` not `except` and neither are available in MySQL! [For MySQL see here for performance comparisons](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT g.id
FROM   Games g
WHERE  finished = 0
       AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                      FROM   Submissions s
                      WHERE  s.user_id = @userid
                             AND s.game_id = g.id)
```

Or (If your RDBMS supports it)

```
SELECT id
FROM   Games
WHERE  finished = 0
EXCEPT
SELECT game_id
FROM   Submissions
WHERE  user_id = @userid
```

Comment: Just tried the first version. Worked like a charm, and since MySQL apparently didn't support EXCEPT I'm going with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT g.id
FROM Games g
    LEFT JOIN Submissions s ON g.id = s.game_id
      AND s.user_id = 1234
WHERE g.finished = 0 AND s.user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: most unclear version, you will forget what it does and get WTF face like a week after doing it and having to look on it again

Comment: @valentin-kuzub It is the standard `NOT EXISTS LEFT JOIN`, which MySql optimizes, and outperforms the `NOT IN()` solution you provided.

Answer (score 2):

```
select g.id from games g
where finished =0 and g.id not in 
(select game_id from submissions s where s.player_id=@playerid)
```

Comment: +1 That's all 4 ways of doing an anti semi join covered now I think!

Comment: I like this & Minus/except version the most  :P

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT G.ID FROM Games G LEFT JOIN Submissions S ON 
(G.ID = S.Game_ID AND S.User_ID = @UserID) 
WHERE G.Finished = 0 AND S.User_ID IS NULL
```

Edited but now similar to others.

Comment: what do you mean <1 ? maybe =0 or you think negative values can happen also who cares whether user_id is <1 ? maybe count(s.user_id)=0 ?. Also HAVING keyword cant be used without group by keyword.

Comment: Additionally the `WHERE S.User_ID = @UserID` would convert your `OUTER JOIN` back into an `INNER JOIN`